# React: call parent version of the functiion when overriding

Tags: reactjs

When I'm overriding a function in a child class, how can I call the parent version of that function?

Say I have two components AbstractList and SortableList in React with:

```
class AbstractList extends React.Component {
  getItems() {
    ...
  }
}

class SortableList extends AbstractList {
  getItems() {
    ... do sorting first
    return super.getItems(); // QUESTION: how am I supported to actually do this?
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do it this way

check this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3280) on github

> Many people have become accustomed to using OO inheritance not just as
>   a tool, but as the primary means of abstraction in their application.
>   I've you've worked at a Java shop, you'll know what I'm talking about.
>   In my personal opinion, classical OO inheritance (as implemented in
>   many popular languages) is not often the best tool for most jobs, let
>   alone all jobs. But the situation should be approached with even more
>   caution when inheritance is used within a framework or paradigm that
>   uses functional composition as its primary abstraction (React). There
>   are certain patterns we'll want to prevent (there are many strange
>   things that people can come up with when combining render with
>   inheritance that don't make sense and are addressed via simple
>   composition). There's also risk of making mutation more convenient. It
>   might make sense to start with ES6 classes simply as a better syntax
>   for React component creation, intentionally limiting some use cases
>   (limiting inheritance depth, making some React base class methods
>   final) (only when used with React components of course - all non-React
>   use of ES6 classes wouldn't be restricted).

Instead of this

```
class AbstractList extends React.Component {
  getItems() {
    ...
  }
}

class SortableList extends AbstractList {
  getItems() {
    ... do sorting first
    return super.getItems(); 
  }
}
```

You should do

```
class AbstractList extends React.Component {
  getItems() {
    ...
  }
}

class SortableList extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return <AbstractList items={this.props.item}>{this.props.children}</AbstractList>;
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome, composition over inheritance. Classic :) Thank you!